# How to use UIView connected as IBOutlet as table view section headers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have my view controller set up like so, with all my UIViews in the XIB,

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *tableHeader, *likesHeader, *commentsHeader, *followersHeader;
```

When the view loads, all the visible section headers appear properly, but as soon as I scroll they disappear. I use the delegate methods to set up the section headers.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return self.tableHeader;
    } else if (section == 1) {
        return self.likesHeader;
    } else if (section == 2) {
        return self.commentsHeader;
    } else if (section == 3) {
        return self.followersHeader;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return 120.0;
    } else {
        return 35.0;
    }
}
```

How did I screw up?

Comment: I would like more detail on what you mean by "disappear". Are they present to start and then if you scroll the slightest amount, do they all just disappear? Or do you mean if they scroll out of the view, they don't reappear when you scroll back up? What's the Use Case?

Comment: Check whether your outlets have become nil in `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`.  I suspect you need to change them from `weak` to `strong`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to change your outlets from `weak` to `strong`.

Since your header views don't start out as subviews of a superview, nothing else references them.  So your weak outlets will become nil and the header views will be deallocated.

You may be successfully returning the headers that are initially visible, because the nib loader may be putting them in an autorelease pool which isn't drained until after the table view asks for them.  When the headers go off the screen, the table view releases them.  Since nothing else retains them, they are deallocated and the system sets your weak outlets to nil.

Answer (score 0):

Change the declaration from `weak` to `strong`.